# Android start VPN without user action

Tags: android, vpn

Is there a way without rooting the device to start VPN connection after reboot which would not ask user to allow the connection every reboot ? (it could ask once and remember)

[Android API 14 docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) says

> User action is required to create a VPN connection.

Is there a way to bypass this by using Device Administration API or any other method ?

This feature is needed to have a firewall, and if user declines, firewall doesn't work which comes down to a lot of company's money spent on expensive mobile internet abroad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've googled quite a bit, and it seems that it's not possible, unless you have some custom SDK from manufacturer.